# WPF Datagrid: Editing values via UI that have been converted using ValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, converters, ivalueconverter

I have a datagrid with a column "Total Amount". This is a double type and is converted by a IValueConverter to a currency type with the "$" symbol and commas.

(1) But the cell needs to be editable so the user can make changes to the row including the amount. How do I do this? Right now, editing freezes the application (not surprised) as I have no clue how to handle this.

(2) If the user adds a new row and adds a new item to it. How do I prefix the value with a $ symbol and add the commas in relevant places as the user types?

**Note:** One workaround is I guess to have the TotalAmount property as a string itself and convert to double when I need to perform any operation. Also add a validation to ensure user inputs a double type. *But I still don't know how to implement point #2.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key here is using the `CellTemplate` & `CellEditingTemplate`

Thanks to - [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18596654/wpf-datagrid-column-format-number-to-include-commas) & [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54774451/wpf-datagrid-binding-to-different-properties-for-displaying-and-editing)

My Solution was the combination of the above two as -

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Total Amount">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TotalAmount, Converter={StaticResource CurrencyConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TotalAmount, StringFormat=\{0:N2\},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```